# How to get multiple values with colors on button click in UI list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple boxes with values and color circles. I want to add all/multiple data in below UL list after click on save button.

What i tried:-

```js
$('.save').click(function() {
  var text = $('.content-box .text').text();
  var color = $('.content-box .color-circle').css('background');
  $('.data-list').append('<li>' + text + '</li>').css('background', color);
});
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.color-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 d-custom-none">
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Success</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-success"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Danger</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Warning</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-warning"></span>
  </div>
  <button class="save btn btn-primary" type="button">Save Data in below list</button>

  <br><br>
  <h5>Below is the list where data will display after click on above save button</h5>
  <ul class="data-list">
  </ul>

</div>
```

I want to added per data in each LI instead of all data coming in single LI.

Answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through your `context-box` `class` `div` element.

Try below working code-

```js
$('.save').click(function() {
  $('.data-list').html('');
  var liElem = '';
  $('.content-box').each(function(index, val){
    var txt = $(val).find('.text').text();
    var bgColor = $(val).find('.color-circle').css('background-color');
    liElem += '<li style="background-color: '+bgColor+'">' + txt + '</li>';
  });
  $('.data-list').append(liElem);
});
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.color-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 d-custom-none">
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Success</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-success"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Danger</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Warning</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-warning"></span>
  </div>
  <button class="save btn btn-primary" type="button">Save Data in below list</button>

  <br><br>
  <h5>Below is the list where data will display after click on above save button</h5>
  <ul class="data-list">
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop all `$('.content-box')` and use `text` and `css` from each to append in `li`

```js
$('.save').click(function() {
  $('.content-box').each((index, box) => {
    var text = $(box).find(".text").text();
    var color = $(box).find(".color-circle").css('background');
    $('.data-list').append('<li style="background:' + color + '">' + text + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.color-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 d-custom-none">
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Success</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-success"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Danger</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Warning</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-warning"></span>
  </div>
  <button class="save btn btn-primary" type="button">Save Data in below list</button>

  <br><br>
  <h5>Below is the list where data will display after click on above save button</h5>
  <ul class="data-list">
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.save').click(function() {
  $('.content-box').map((i,v)=>{
    let text = $(v).find(".text").text();
    let color = $(v).find(".color-circle").css('background');
    $('.data-list').append($('<li>' + text + '</li>').css('background', color));
  });
  
});
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.color-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 d-custom-none">
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Success</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-success"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Danger</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text" >Warning</span>
    <span class="color-circle bg-warning"></span>
  </div>
  <button class="save btn btn-primary" type="button">Save Data in below list</button>

  <br><br>
  <h5>Below is the list where data will display after click on above save button</h5>
  <ul class="data-list">
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: The OP's didn't store their element's `background-color` in `data` attributes. So please get color from `background-color` CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

You've basically fetched and applied the `text` and `background` properties of a single element, whereas you need to do it for all of them. To get these values for each one, you got to loop through them in order to fetch and use them ahead.

I've tried to create a snippet of a solution for your said problem statement. Do check and let me know if that's what you require.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".save", function() {
  var $dataList = $(".data-list");

  $(".content-box").each(function() {
    let text = $(this).find(".text").text();
    let color = $(this).find(".color-circle").css("background");

    let $listItem = $("<li/>", {
      class: "result-list-item"
    });

    $listItem.css("background", color);
    $listItem
      .html(text)
      .appendTo($dataList);
  });
});
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.color-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-12 d-custom-none">
  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Success</span>

    <span class="color-circle bg-success"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Danger</span>

    <span class="color-circle bg-danger"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="content-box">
    <span class="text">Warning</span>

    <span class="color-circle bg-warning"></span>
  </div>

  <button class="save btn btn-primary" type="button">Save Data in below list</button>

  <br><br>

  <h5>Below is the list where data will display after click on above save button</h5>

  <ul class="data-list">
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Cheers!